# Duda con ListBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms, listbox

**Buenas, estoy tratando de cargar un `ListBox` con datos `SQl` pero por algún motivo no me está mostrando los datos. Cuando llego a esta línea:

```
p = new Personas(persona);
```

El `debug` me muestra los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, en la siguiente línea no me muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la clase conexión, pido los datos así:

```
    public List<Personas> cargarLista(Personas p)
    {
        List<Personas> salida = new List<Personas>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT nombre + ' ' +  apellido + ' - ' + LTRIM(STR(dninumero, 25,0)) AS persona " +
                "FROM v_solicitudweb " +
                "WHERE provincia = @pro " +
                "AND asesor = @ase " +
                "AND ancantcuoplan = @cuo";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", p.provincias);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ase", p.asesor);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuo", p.tipoPlan);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string persona = dr["persona"]?.ToString();
                        p = new Personas(persona);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

En el **form** hago este método:

```
    private void lista()
    {
        Personas p = new Personas();
        p.provincias = cmbProvincias.SelectedValue.ToString();
        p.asesor = cmbAsesor.SelectedValue.ToString();
        p.tipoPlan = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPlan.SelectedValue.ToString());
        if(p.provincias != "" && p.asesor != "" && p.tipoPlan != 0)
        {
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            lstPersonas.ValueMember = "dninumero";
            lstPersonas.DisplayMember = "persona";
            lstPersonas.DataSource = conexionSQL.cargarLista(p);
        }
    }
```

Y desde el evento lo cargo:

```
    private void cmbTipoPlan_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lista();
    }
```

Esta es la clase:

```
class Personas
{
    public string provincias { get; set; }
    public string asesor { get; set; }
    public int tipoPlan { get; set; }
    public double dni { get; set; }
    public string persona { get; set; }


    public Personas(string persona)
    {
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    public Personas(string persona, double dni)
    {
        this.persona = persona;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Personas() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return persona + " - " + tipoPlan.ToString();
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de dónde puede estar el fallo?

Comment: Intenta modificando esta linea: p = new Personas(persona); para que te crees una nueva variable desde adentro y no reuses la de p de tu parámetro, en teoría el código de la clase  Personas está bien

Comment: Veo que haces un override de string... 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return persona + " - " + tipoPlan.ToString();
    }

En la consulta utilizas concatenar persona y tipo de plan...

    SELECT nombre + ' ' +  apellido + ' - ' + LTRIM(STR(dninumero, 25,0)) AS persona 


Ademas utilizas un ? en dr["persona"] eso indica que pueden haber nulos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que haces un override de string...

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return persona + " - " + tipoPlan.ToString();
}
```

En la consulta utilizas concatenar persona y tipo de plan...

```
SELECT nombre + ' ' +  apellido + ' - ' + LTRIM(STR(dninumero, 25,0)) AS persona
```

Fijate en el where si No encuentra registros al parametrizar asesor, provincias y todos los que están filtrando

Comment: En la consulta, si me arroja resultados. De hecho, en las capturas se ve que me trae los valores.